# Making a UserControl static WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, static, user-controls

I have an application called `MyApp`.

I also have the following two `UserControls`:

1) `UC1`.

2) `UC2` - A `UserControl` which only contains a `ListBox`.

Both `UC1` and `UC2` are referenced in `MyApp`. `UC2` is referenced in `UC1` as well.

I wish to treat `UC2` as a `Logger`. Hence, I would like to access the `UC2`'s `LisBox` statically, from both `UC1` and `MyApp`. I want to place it on my main window of `MyApp` but access it from all projects referenced to `MyApp`.

I tried to make `UC2` static without any luck.

Is that even possible?

Comment: What was the error you had when you made this Static? If you are attempting to make a user control static I do not believe this is possible.

Comment: I wrote `public static partial class AppLogger` and got an error: `'InitializeComponent': cannot declare instance members in a static class` But there are 9 more errors regarding this error.

Comment: You cannot make class static, however, you can create a static accessor to your listbox

Comment: You mean `'Property`? If so then I know I can, isn't there a better way of doing it?

Comment: UserControls are not really defined for this utilisation, because they contains graphical elements which need instanciation. You cannot access your listbox before instantiate it. This is why you need normal constructor and after, a static property to manager your listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserControls are not really defined for this utilisation, because they contains graphical elements which need instanciation. You cannot access your listbox before instantiate it. This is why you need normal constructor (with InitializeComponent()) and after, a static property to manage your listbox.

However, a better solution would be to have a static class as logger, and bind your usercontrol to this class (bind your listbox to your logger attached property).